# Items in the array is getting repeated

Tags: javascript, arrays

my array name is getting repeated when trying to pass in for loop.

Here I am showing users which contains in same branch only.

```
const content_id = '34566553';
          const user_name = 'ray';
this.userDataAsResponse = { 'objectid': 'do_31297612465', 'users' : [
            {
              'userid' : 'u001',
              'username': 'ray',
              'batchcode': 'b001',
              'useravatar': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d7d232a9c0d488c843719989a9bb3671?s=800&d=identicon'
            },
            {
              'userid' : 'u004',
              'username': 'umang',
              'batchcode': 'b001',
              'useravatar': 'https://conceptdraw.com/a3179c3/p7/preview/640/pict--clerk,-man-sales-symbols-vector-stencils-library'
            },
            {
              'userid' : 'u002',
              'username': 'robin',
              'batchcode': 'b001',
              'useravatar': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d7d232a9c0d488c843719989a9bb3671?s=800&d=identicon'
            },
            {
              'userid' : 'u005',
              'username': 'riki',
              'batchcode': 'b001’,
              'useravatar': 'https://conceptdraw.com/a3179c3/p21/preview/640/pict--customer,-woman-sales-symbols-vector-stencils-library'
            },
            {
              'userid' : 'u006',
              'username': 'george',
              'batchcode': 'b001’,
              'useravatar': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d7d232a9c0d488c843719989a9bb3671?s=800&d=identicon'
            },
            {
              'userid' : 'u007',
              'username': 'goof',
              'batchcode': 'b003',
   'useravatar':'https://conceptdraw.com/a3179c3/p7/preview/640/pict--clerk,-man-sales-symbols-vector-stencils-library'
            }
          ]};

         for ( const i in this.userDataAsResponse.users ) {
          if (this.userDataAsResponse.users[i].username  === user_name) {
            this.batchCode = this.userDataAsResponse.users[i].batchcode;
          }
         }

         for (const k in this.userDataAsResponse.users) {
          if (this.batchCode === this.userDataAsResponse.users[k].batchcode) {
            this.showUser[this.j] = this.userDataAsResponse.users[k].username;
              this.userUrl[this.j] = this.userDataAsResponse.users[k].useravatar;
              this.j = this.j + 1;
              console.log('j value’, this.j);
              console.log('show user', this.showUser); //<——  here the values getting added repeatedly.
        }
       }
```

*So the data is coming in this way:-*

```
show user [“ray”]
display.component.ts:432 j valur 2
display.component.ts:433 show user (2) [“ray”, “umang”]
display.component.ts:432 j valur 3
display.component.ts:433 show user (3) [“ray”, “umang”, “robin”]
display.component.ts:432 j valur 4
display.component.ts:433 show user (4) [“ray”, “umang”, “robin”, “riki”]
display.component.ts:432 j valur 5
display.component.ts:433 show user (5) [“ray”, “umang”, “robin”, “riki”, “george”]
display.component.ts:432 j valur 6
display.component.ts:433 show user (6) [“ray”, “umang”, “robin”, “riki”, “george”]
show user (7) [“ray”, “umang”, “robin”, “riki”, “george”, “ray”]
display.component.ts:432 j valur 8
display.component.ts:433 show user (8) [“ray”, “umang”, “robin”, “riki”, “george”, “ray”, “umang”]
```

Same way it is repeating upto `show user(18)`

How to stop repeating in this for loop ? Where am I going wrong ?
Anything needed to be shown. then please ask.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: what is `this.j`? Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example?

Comment: @KurtHamilton `[“ray”, “umang”, “robin”, “riki”, “george”]` only once. Also because they are in same batch.

Comment: @StepUp j = 0 ;

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems excessively complex.

You want to store (and log) a single array of user names for users matching a certain condition. Array functions are your friend here.

I have recreated your example in a simplified manner to focus on the usage of array functions.

```js
batchCode = 'b001';
showUser = [];
userUrl = [];

ngOnInit() {
  // Create a new array containing only users matching a certain condition
  // In this case the condition is that the batch code matches
  const users = this.userDataAsResponse.users
    .filter(x => x.batchcode === this.batchCode);

  // create a new array containing only the username strings
  this.showUser = users.map(x => x.username);

  // you were doing this on every loop as you were building the showUser array,
  // which is why you were seeing duplicates
  console.log('show user', this.showUser);
}
```

This answer is to show you *how* you use array functions and what kind of approach would be better - it's not a complete solution (as we don't know what the full requirements are).

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ru9x5

Comment: I don't want to hard code the batchCode. Condition must check within the function only.

Comment: Ok , I forgot to add few details. I added above the json. Here I am checking if the user entered is from the array, then check the batch of that particular user and give result of usernames from that batch. For that I had used this condition `if (this.userDataAsResponse.users[i].username  === user_name) {
   this.batchCode = this.userDataAsResponse.users[i].batchcode;
     }`. So i had mentioned batch code as   `public batchCode: any;`

Comment: I stated in the answer that it wasn't a complete solution. The question was about how to log the array of users once. I've presented a clean solution focussing on how to build the arrays. You should be able to work out how to apply the method I have shown you to your existing code.

Comment: Has this answered your original question as it was stated?

Comment: Got the idea. Even after trying by this approach, I am getting an empty array.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz like I did to show me what you're doing